# Not able to Login to social media site in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-webview

I have multiple social media platform in my app like facebook, pinterest, flickr etc. I have opened these sites in my WebView. The problem is this when I open site in WebView it opens perfectly but when I tried to logged into any Social Media Site like I want to open my account in pinterest and I want to login using facebook or gmail it does not show anything. WebView show blank page. Please tell me the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have javascript enabled in your webview?

It's possible that these sites use Ajax for login so you may need to enable it.

Comment: you can post that om comment

Comment: Hi sorry, I'm only new to the SO game so I don't have enough reputation to post a comment on other peoples questions

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the tips below:

1. At first, go to your MainActivity.java file
2. Go to your onCreate
3. then slightly scroll down and you will see---

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

4. After setContentView... you just add this code....
   (set your own variable name and then dot. getSetiings....)

```
  YourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

5. Make sure that your setWebViewClient is active here....like

```
  YourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```